# Docker spring boot oauth

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, oauth

I'm hoping that someone can help me out here.

I'll try to give as much information as I can but this is a work project so have to be very careful how much I post.

The situation is this. The user attempts to connect to a web page, as they are not authenticated they are re-directed to an oauth server and are presented with a login page. When the user completes login they are then re-directed back to the original URL and are presented with the landing page.

The projects are spring boot and when I run them locally everything works as intended.
I have created docker images and can run the containers and the projects are connecting to a eureka server with on the correct network with the correct hostname.

The issue that I have is that when I attempt to get to the web page, I can track the logs and see that the re-direct is happening and I can see the re-direct URL in the browser bar but then it seems to stop. The oauth server logs shows that nothing is happening and there is no login page presented. The web UI and the oauth server are both docker images and both use spring boot with java 8.

There isn't a firewall issue as the containers are running on the same subnet. The projects are copies of projects that are already running in another section of the network so I know that they do run ok.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ok so an update to this, it turns out that the server running the docker engine was running on a unix server but that was actually running inside of a Hyper-V container which was interfering with the network traffic and the redirects, I asked to have the image removed and started working on the windows server directly, I would have preferred to work on unix but there we go. So if you are working remotely where you are deploying docker images to a container engine on a remote server and getting redirect issues, this may be one thing to look at, especially if you can run your system locally without any issues.